# PHP/Jquery issue populating 3 dynamic select boxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am quite new to PHP and JQuery and am struggling with 3 dynamic select boxes. The first one should contain a list of my instruments. The second one a list of categories, and the third should contain a list of subcategories, based on the selected value of the category and selected instrument. Have followed some great tutorials on the matter, but none seem exactly what I need. So far, managed to populate the instruments and the categories select box correctly, but when clicking on the categories select box to select the value I want, it malfunctions, the subcategories box stay empty. I believe the problem is because I do not send the instrumentID correctly when the categories onchange occurs, but cannot seem to find how to properly send it. Can anyone help me please ?
This is my code so far :

```
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM instruments ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = $db->query($query)->results();
  ?>
<div class = "form-group col-md-3>"
  <select name="instrument_id" id="instrument_id">
    <option value="">-Select Instrument-</option>
    <?php
      foreach($result as $row){
        echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
      }
    ?>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
      <label for="category_id" class="control-label">Category</label>
      <select id="category_id" name="category_id" class="form-control input-sm">
        <option value="">-Select Category-</option>
      </select>

</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="subcategory_id" class="control-label">Subcategory</label>
  <select id="subcategory_id" name="subcategory_id" class="form-control input-sm">
    <option value="">-Select Subcategory-</option>
  </select>
</div>

    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#instrument_id').on('change', function(){
    const instrumentID = $(this).val();
    if(instrumentID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?=PROOT?>admindocuments/get_categories',
            data:{instrument_id: instrumentID},
            success:function(html){
                $('#category_id').html(html);
                $('#subcategory_id').html('<option value="">-Select  Subcategory-</option>');
            }
        });
    }else{
            $('#category_id').html('<option value="">-Select Category-   </option>');
        $('#subcategory_id').html('<option value="">-Select Subcategory-  </option>');
    }
});

$('#category_id').on('change', function(){
    const categoryID = $(this).val();
    const instrumentID = $('#instrument_id').val();
    if(categoryID){
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'<?=PROOT?>admindocuments/get_subcategories',
            data: {
              category_id: categoryID,
              instrument_id: instrumentID,
            },
            success:function(html){
                $('#subcategory_id').html(html);
            }
        });
    }else{
        $('#subcategory_id').html('<option value="">-Select Subcategory-      </option>');
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

And this is the code in my get_categories.php and get_subcategories.php file :

```
get_categories :
<?php    
  if($_POST["instrument_id"]){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC";
    $result = $db->query($query)->results();
    echo '<option value="">-Select Category-</option>';
    foreach($result as $row){
    echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
  }
}
?>
```

get_subcategories :

```
<?php
    if($_POST["category_id"] && !empty($_POST["instrument_id"])){
  $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id =  ".$_POST['category_id']." AND instrument_id = ".$_POST['instrument_id']."  ORDER BY name ASC";
      $result = $db->query($query)->results();
    echo '<option value="">-Select Subcategory-</option>';
    foreach($result as $row){
      echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong ? Please help me.
Kind regards

Comment: It helps to check your browser's network tab in the devtools. What is the response returned by the server when you call `get_subcategories.php'` when the onchange event is fired from `#category_id`?

Comment: You're not sending the instrument id at all when category changes, you need to add it to data. But even if you did, your code would fail because of the `if-elseif` structure (it would always enter the first branch).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and help ! I checked the network tab, and as I suspected it said it didn't recognize instrument_id. Did the changes in the code as El Vanja suggested. Now, that error has cleared, but still the subcategories box stays empty after selecting instrument and category .. :( Getting closer but still not there yet it seems .. :)

Answer (score 0):

The root of your problem is that you aren't sending the instrument id at all when getting subcategories. First you need to fetch it in your handler, since your `select` has an id, it's easy:

```js
$('#category_id').on('change', function(){
    const categoryID = $(this).val(); // I changed var to const here, read more about it below
    const instrumentID = $('#instrument_id').val(); // this line added
```

[Here](https://medium.com/@pandeysoni/when-should-use-const-and-let-instead-of-var-in-javascript-ec2c3d7e5ca6) you can read about using `const` and `let` over `var`.

And then you need to send it in AJAX `data`:

```js
// sending it as an object is more readable and PHP reads it just the same
data: {
    category_id: categoryID,
    instrument_id: instrumentID,
}
```

Now you also need to fix your PHP side. As it currently stands, if you send this kind of data, your first branch would be activated because instrument id is set in both cases:

```php
if (!empty($_POST["instrument_id"])) {
    // get categories
} elseif(!empty($_POST["category_id"])) {
    // get subcategories
}
```

What you should be checking for instead is if *both* parameters are set (that's how you determine you need subcategories):

```php
if (!empty($_POST["instrument_id"]) && !empty($_POST["category_id"])) {
    // get subcategories
} elseif (!empty($_POST["category_id"]) && empty($_POST["instrument_id"])) {
    // get categories
}
```

But a much cleaner solution would be to simply have two PHP scripts, one for categories and one for subcategories. Then you wouldn't need this complex `if-elseif` structure and your tasks would be logically separated (currently, you're using a file called `get_subcategories` to get both subcategories *and* categories, so it isn't really aptly named).

Another thing you should avoid at all costs is building queries by directly inserting parameters:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND instrument_id = ".$_POST['instrument_id']." ORDER BY name ASC";
```

This kind of practice leaves you wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). You should use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead.

Comment: Thanks, will read the articles you suggested and have made the changes in the code as you suggested, but the subcategories select box stays empty after selecting instrument and categories. :( Do you mean pointing to 2 php files instead ? (get_categories.php and get_subcategories.php for example and just use if ($_POST["instrument_id")) ?

Comment: Yes, point to 2 files, each executing one of the queries. Do you see any errors in the browser console? What does the network tab say?

Comment: ok, have pointed to 2 files now, but still nothing appearing in the subcategories box. :( Have changed my code in the 2 files. (Will address the SQL injection issue after I get the boxes operational)

Comment: if(isset($_POST["instrument_id"])){
      $query = "SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY name ASC";
      $result = $db->query($query)->results();
           echo '<option value="">-Select Category-</option>';
        foreach($result as $row){
          echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        }
    }

Comment: if(isset($_POST["category_id"]) && isset($_POST["instrument_id"])){
      $query = "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE category_id = ".$_POST['category_id']." AND instrument_id = ".$_POST['instrument_id']." ORDER BY name ASC";
      $result = $db->query($query);
        echo '<option value="">-Select Subcategory-</option>';
        foreach($result as $row){
          echo '<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.$row->name.'</option>';
        }
    }

Comment: Please add any code changes to the question by editing, it's difficult to read in the comments. Have you tried debugging the query, does it actually give results? You can see the output of your AJAX PHP script in the developer toolbar network tab.

Comment: I have changed my code as seen edited in the original posted question, and now it is working !! Thank you so much for all the help ! :) Now I will try to fix the SQL injection matter ..